# Regular expression to match text outside angle brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to replace all specific word occurrences outside angle brackets.

For example:

I want to replace "is" word in this string:

```xml
this is a <sample> string with <some> special words. this <is another> one
```

Find all "is" words out side the angle brackets, expected output:

```xml
th*is* *is* a <sample> string with <some> special words. this <is another> one
```

Comment: Could you add some more clarification on restrictions. For example, why `this` in  `this <is another> one` isn't replaced? Can you also add your regular expression as you may be close to an answer yourself =). Also technically, `is` in `This` isn't a "word" on it's own as per your requirement, rather a substring.

Comment: Please don't destroy the updates we make to your question.

Comment: What are the angle brackets here? It's not HTML, is it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression with a negative look-ahead, which will check that there is no closing `>` following a potential match, without any preceding `<`:

```js
let s = "this is a <sample> string with <some> special words. this <is another> one";

let result = s.replace(/is(?![^<>]*>)/g, "*$&*");

console.log(result);
```

Note that it will also match a third "is" by that logic.